# How to transform a webcam image to grayscale using TensorflowJS?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I am trying to use a model to classify grayscale images.

I used the [Webcam class](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/blob/master/webcam-transfer-learning/webcam.js) provided in some of the TensorflowJS examples to get an image using the webcam. It worked well, but it returns an RGB image.

What is the best way to transform this image to grayscale? Do I need to compute this getting each element from the tensor and compute a new matrix that represents the grayscale image or is there a more simple or convenient way?

Answer (score 7):

If you need to have it in the form [width, height, 1]:

```
tf.browser.fromPixels(image)
    .mean(2)
    .toFloat()
    .expandDims(-1)
```

If you need in the form [1, width, height, 1]:

```
tf.browser.fromPixels(image)
    .mean(2)
    .toFloat()
    .expandDims(0)
    .expandDims(-1)
```

Answer (score 4):

To convert the image to grayscale, the depth channel dimension should be removed or be reduced to one.

Given a tensor t, here is two ways of doing it

1. Averaging the depth dimension

```js
tensor.mean(2)
```

2. Slicing the tensor

```js
tensor.slice([0, 0, 0], [a.shape[0], a.shape[1], 1])
```

[tf.toPixels](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#toPixels) displays an image from a tensor.

3 - Transposing the channel (HWC -> CHW)

By transposing the channel, the 2D underlying images can be unstacked in an array since toPixel can be used with a 2D tensor as well

```
const c = a.transpose([2, 0, 1]).unstack()[0];
```

```js
const im = new Image()
im.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
im.src = "https://i.imgur.com/lVlPvCB.gif"
document.body.appendChild(im)
im.onload = () => {
  const a = tf.fromPixels(im, 4)
  
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            const canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
            const canvas2 = document.createElement('canvas');

            tf.toPixels(a.mean(2).div(255.0), canvas);
            const b = a.slice([0, 0, 0], [a.shape[0], a.shape[1], 1])
            tf.toPixels(b, canvas1);

            const c = a.transpose([2, 0, 1]).unstack()[0];
            tf.toPixels(c, canvas2);

            document.body.append(canvas);
            document.body.append(canvas1);
            document.body.append(canvas2);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.14.1/dist/tf.min.js"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Grayscale conversion as described in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_%28video%29)

```
const rgb = tf.tensor1d([0.2989, 0.587, 0.114])
return tf.sum(image.mul(rgb), 2) // broadcasting
```

Answer (score 4):

The preferred way to get grayscale from an RGB image is per the ITU-R recommendations (BT.601). It is how matlab, OpenCV, and Tensorflow (python) all do it.

gray = 0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B

If so, the best way I can think of doing it is with a simple example that should expand to any size image:

```
// make an image that is size 2x2, with 3 color channels
x = tf.randomUniform([2, 2, 3]);

// print out the tensor so you know what you started with
x.print();

// the scalars needed for conversion of each channel
// per the formula: gray = 0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B
rFactor = tf.scalar(0.2989);
gFactor = tf.scalar(0.5870);
bFactor = tf.scalar(0.1140);

// separate out each channel. x.shape[0] and x.shape[1] will give you
// the correct dimensions regardless of image size
r = x.slice([0,0,0], [x.shape[0], x.shape[1], 1]);
g = x.slice([0,0,1], [x.shape[0], x.shape[1], 1]);
b = x.slice([0,0,2], [x.shape[0], x.shape[1], 1]);

// add all the tensors together, as they should all be the same dimensions.
gray = r.mul(rFactor).add(g.mul(gFactor)).add(b.mul(bFactor));

// check your work
gray.print();
```

Answer (score 1):

A 3D tensor that represents an image has this shape: (height, width, number_of_channels). So, a RGB image has the shape (height, width, 3).

To convert to grayscale, I calculated the mean using the last axis (the number_of_channels axis). Thus, every pixel value is now the mean of the R, G, and B values.

```
grayscale_image = image.mean(2)
```

This operation removes the last dimension of the tensor, returning a tensor with shape (height, width).

To keep the shape (height, width, number_of_channels), I expanded the dimensions:

```
final_image = grayscale_image.expandDims(2)
```

final_image has the shape (height, width, 1)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me was to first average the RGB channel values, then use [tf.stack](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.14.1/#stack) to duplicate the averaged value and make the image shape appropriate for RGB once again.

An example:

```
// load a tensor from a canvas image
let t = await tf.fromPixels(canvas, 3);

// at this point shape should be [width, height, 3]

// now average along the channel dimension to get average of RGB for each pixel
t = t.mean(2);

// at this point shape should be [width, height]

// finally, repeat each monochrome value three times to get our shape back to RGB
t = tf.stack([t, t, t], 2);

// final shape is again [width, height, 3]
```