# How to easily import OpenCV.js into a .js file?

Tags: javascript, opencv, tensorflow.js

I implemented a CNN that I use on a web application via Tensorflow.js.

I need to preprocess my webcam photos to be accepted by my CNN model. So I want to use OpenCV.js in my `.js` file but I can't figure out how to simply import this library into my .js file where I turn my canvasElement into a tensor using the `tf.browser.fromPixels()` function of Tensorflow.js.

The tutorials I see show the use of OpenCV.js in the `.html` file directly inside a `<script>`, whereas I would like to use it in my javascript file.

I would especially like to use the method `cv.cvtColor()`. If not, do you have another solution to convert my canvasElement to grayscale?

Comment: If the code is in the tag script, you can put it in your js function. If you wonder if you can convert a canvasElement to grayscale using tfjs, please look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334200/how-to-transform-a-webcam-image-to-grayscale-using-tensorflowjs/53751023#53751023

Comment: Your solution for grayscale convertion to tfjs use the same method as OpenCV ? I need to provide the same type of image as my dataset I created with OpenCV color convertion method. I have already used the methods of this topic but I have so many wrong predictions so I think the grayscale conversion is wrong

Comment: Could you please show your code with your script tag ?

Comment: I have a `<script src="static/prediction.js"></script>` in my `.html` file, and inside my `.js` file I do all my preprocessing image and call Tensorflow.js. I would rather like to use OpenCV next to Tensorflow.js in my .js file. Is it possible ?

Comment: It is possible. I don't see what will prevent you for doing so

Answer (score 0):

The script tag will import OpenCV into the webpage (be sure to load this before you load your code that needs to use it - order matters in HTML). You should then be able to access the OpenCV class / object to call its functions with your canvas data to do your pre processing, and then write that back out and convert to tensor in TF.js land.

If you want to quickly convert canvas to greyscale there are many ways to do this -  eg how you average the colours etc will effect the greyscale image you get out.

Here is one method: http://www.vapidspace.com/coding/2012/02/26/converting-images-to-grayscale-using-the-canvas/

Here is the code from that site in case it gets removed:

```
function grayscale (input,output) {
    //Get the context for the loaded image
    var inputContext = input.getContext("2d");
    //get the image data;
    var imageData = inputContext.getImageData(0, 0, input.width, input.height);
    //Get the CanvasPixelArray
    var data = imageData.data;

    //Get length of all pixels in image each pixel made up of 4 elements for each pixel, one for Red, Green, Blue and Alpha
    var arraylength = input.width * input.height * 4;
    //Go through each pixel from bottom right to top left and alter to its gray equiv

    //Common formula for converting to grayscale.
    //gray = 0.3*R + 0.59*G + 0.11*B
    for (var i=arraylength-1; i>0;i-=4)
    {
        //R= i-3, G = i-2 and B = i-1
        //Get our gray shade using the formula
        var gray = 0.3 * data[i-3] + 0.59 * data[i-2] + 0.11 * data[i-1];
        //Set our 3 RGB channels to the computed gray.
        data[i-3] = gray;
        data[i-2] = gray;
        data[i-1] = gray;

    }

    //get the output context
    var outputContext = output.getContext("2d");

    //Display the output image
    outputContext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
```

Notice here how they use a formula to calc gray. Depending on your needs you may want to use different ratios of the RGB mix to get the grayscale image.

Personally I would strongly recommend using vanilla JS here as it's very easy to do and you dont need to include OpenCV just to do grayscale which is a massive overhead to include that file for such a task. If you are using some of the more advanced features of OpenCV too then maybe that is a reason to then use it.