# resizing and changing to gray scale

Tags: javascript, react-native, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to take a jpg photo, and make it grayscale and resize it to 48x48 for my model,
I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
let image = require("../assets/angry.jpg");
      const imageAssetPath = Image.resolveAssetSource(image);
      const response = await fetch(imageAssetPath.uri, {}, { isBinary: true });
      const imageData = await response.arrayBuffer();
      let imageTensor = imageToTensor(imageData);
      const imageResize = tf.image.resizeBilinear(imageTensor, [48, 48], true);



  const imageToTensor = (rawData: ArrayBuffer) => {
    const { width, height, data } = jpeg.decode(rawData, true);
    const buffer = new Uint8Array(width * height * 3);
    let offset = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; i += 3) {
      buffer[i] = data[offset]; //red
      buffer[i + 1] = data[offset + 1]; //green
      buffer[i + 2] = data[offset + 2]; //blue
      offset += 4; //skips Alpha value
    }
    return tf.tensor4d(buffer, [1, height, width, 3]);
  };
```

the image is resizing to 48x48 but how do I make it grayscale?  I tried in imageToTensor function to change the array to [height,width,1] but it only messed up the picture, any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transform a webcam image to grayscale using TensorflowJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334200/how-to-transform-a-webcam-image-to-grayscale-using-tensorflowjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know there are so many methods missing!
You can look at the source of `rgb_to_grayscale` in [python](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.1/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py#L2105-L2138)
and you'll see, how they convert rgb images to grayscale.

I tried to implement it the same way in javascript, but there is no function called `tf.tensordot`.

Here's how you can do it.

```
image = tf.ones([224, 224, 3])
rgb_weights = [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140]
image = tf.mul(image, rgb_weights)
image = tf.sum(image, axis=-1)
image = tf.expandDims(image, axis=-1)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I need it in javascript instead of python

Comment: @AlexK I completely changed the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer!! but axis=-1 is not a valid syntax, is it 'axis=1' or something?

Comment: found it , instead of axis=-1 its just -1, thanks!!