# Tensorflowjs Unhandled Rejection (Error): The shape of dict['input_1'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be [-1,380,380,1], but was [1,380,380,3]

Tags: reactjs, keras, tensorflow.js

**EDIT: Seeing there are many similar questions, however none of the solutions have worked for me. Thought this might be useful information: In my model.json file I have the following: `"tensorShape": {"dim": [{"size": "3"}, {"size": "3"}, {"size": "512"}, {"size": "1"}]}}}`**

Getting two errors here. I have a keras model which has been converted to a `tfjs_graph_model` that should return a **binary classification** when given **a single image**. Getting it to work on `tensorflowjs` however is proving a challenge given it's my first time using this technology.

The first one `Error: The shape of dict['input_1'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be [-1,380,380,1], but was [1,380,380,3]` results from the following snippet of code in my react component.

```
const imageElement = document.createElement("img");
        imageElement.src = file;
        imageElement.width = 380;
        imageElement.height = 380;

        imageElement.onload = async () => {
          const tensor = tf.browser
            .fromPixels(imageElement)
            .resizeNearestNeighbor([380, 380])
            .expandDims()
            .toFloat();

          const prediction = await model.predict(tensor).data();
          console.log(prediction);
          setPrediction(parseInt(prediction, 10));
          setProcessing(false);
          setImageLoaded(false);
        };
```

However when I seem to resize it to [-1,380,380,1] using the following snippet, it then returns the error `Error: Tensor must have a shape comprised of positive integers but got shape [-1,380,380,1].`

```
const imageElement = document.createElement("img");
        imageElement.src = file;
        imageElement.width = 380;
        imageElement.height = 380;

        imageElement.onload = async () => {
          const tfImg = tf.browser.fromPixels(imageElement);
          const smalImg = tf.image.resizeBilinear(tfImg, [380, 380]);
          const resized = tf.cast(smalImg, "float32");
          const tensor = tf.tensor4d(Array.from(resized.dataSync()), [
            -1,
            380,
            380,
            1,
          ]);

          const prediction = await model.predict(tensor).data();
          console.log(prediction);
          setPrediction(parseInt(prediction, 10));
          setProcessing(false);
          setImageLoaded(false);
        };
```

If I try to resize it to `[1,380,380,1]` then the error is `Error: Based on the provided shape, [1,380,380,1], the tensor should have 144400 values but has 433200`.

I don't understand why this is happening or if I am resizing the image or transforming it correctly.

Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Comment: What is the input shape of the keras model?

Comment: Could you try `const tensor = resized.reshape([1, 380,380,1])` and then make a prediction with `const prediction = await model.predict(tensor, { batchSize: 1 });`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a shape mismatch. You are using 3 channels for the image instead of a single one.

There are several ways to compute a grayscale image (channel = 1) from a colorful image (channel = 3). The same processing that is applied while training the model should be applied here. But if you are looking for a quick way to convert your shape to the shape expected by the model, this one will get you covered:

```
const tensorWithCorrectShape = tf.mean(tensor, 3, true)
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334200/how-to-transform-a-webcam-image-to-grayscale-using-tensorflowjs/53751023#53751023) discusses several ways to get a grayscale image